# quartus how convert four input to two inputs in block?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, multiplexing, intel-fpga, mux

how can i convert entity of bloch which takes 4 inputs to 2 inputs?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2879760/sample.PNG
A you see here i use three the same mux :( how to take in etykieta2 only two inputs?
code:

```
library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  library work; --domyslnie zawieta moj pakiet

  use work.mux_package.all;

  entity glowny is

            generic(
                n : integer := 4;
                k : integer := 2
            );
            port(
                a, b, c, d,e,f,g,h : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
                s : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
                t : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
                y, x, z : out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)
            );
        end glowny;

architecture multiplekser of glowny is

signal xx,yy,zz : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0); 

    for etykieta: mux use entity work.mux(arch_mux5);
    for etykieta1: mux use entity work.mux(arch_mux6);
    for etykieta2: mux use entity work.mux(arch_mux3);

    begin

    etykieta:
    mux generic map (n=>n) port map (a=> a, b=>b, c=>c, d=>d,s=>s, y=>xx);

    etykieta1:
    mux generic map (n=>n) port map (a=> e, b=>f, c=>g, d=>h,s=>s,y=>yy);

    etykieta2:
    mux generic map (n=>n) port map (a=> yy , b=>yy, c=> xx, d=>xx, s=>t ,y=>zz);



end multiplekser;
```

packages

```
    library ieee;
      use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
        entity mux is

            generic(
                n : integer := 4
            );
            port(
                a, b, c, d : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
                s : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
                y : out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)
            );
        end mux;



      -- przypisanie podstawowe - concurrent signal assigment

      architecture arch_mux1 of mux is

        begin

            y(0) <= (a(0) and not(s(1)) and not(s(0)))
                or (b(0) and not(s(1)) and s(0))
                or (c(0) and s(1) and not(s(0)))
                or (d(0) and s(1) and s(0));

            y(1) <= (a(1) and not(s(1)) and not(s(0)))
                or (b(1) and not(s(1)) and s(0))
                or (c(1) and s(1) and not(s(0)))
                or (d(1) and s(1) and s(0));

            y(2) <= (a(2) and not(s(1)) and not(s(0)))
                or (b(2) and not(s(1)) and s(0))
                or (c(2) and s(1) and not(s(0)))
                or (d(2) and s(1) and s(0));

            y(3) <= (a(3) and not(s(1)) and not(s(0)))
                or (b(3) and not(s(1)) and s(0))
                or (c(3) and s(1) and not(s(0)))
                or (d(3) and s(1) and s(0));

        end arch_mux1;



      -- przypisanie warunkowe - conditional signal assigment
      architecture arch_mux2 of mux is
        begin
            with s select
                y <= a when "00",
                b when "01",
                c when "10",
                d when others;
      end arch_mux2;

      -- przypisanie selektywne - selected signal assigment

      architecture arch_mux3 of mux is
        begin
            y <= a when (s = "00") else
            b when (s = "01") else
            c when (s = "10") else
            d;
      end arch_mux3;

      architecture arch_mux4 of mux is
        begin
            pr_if: process(a,b,c,d,s) --lista czulosci
            begin

                case s is
                    when "00" => y <= a; -- czytamy y :=
                    when "01" => y <= b;
                    when "10" => y <= c;
                    --when "11" => y <= d;
                        y <= (others => '0');
                    when others => y <= d;
                end case;

            end process;

        end arch_mux4;

        architecture arch_mux5 of mux is
        begin
            pr_if: process(a,b,c,d,s) --lista czulosci
            begin

                if s ="00" then
                    y <= a;
                elsif s="01" then
                    y <=b;
                elsif s="10" then
                    y <=c;
                else
                    y <=d;
                end if;
            end process;

        end arch_mux5;

        architecture arch_mux6 of mux is
        begin
            pr_if: process(a,b,c,d,s) --lista czulosci
            begin

                y<=(others=>'0');

                if s ="00" then
                    y <= a;
                end if;

                if s ="01" then
                    y <= b;
                end if;

                if s ="10" then
                    y <= c;
                end if;

--              if s ="11" then
--                  y <= d;
--              end if;

            end process;

        end arch_mux6;

        architecture arch_mux7 of mux is
        begin
            pr_if: process(a,b,c,d,s) --lista czulosci
            begin

                   --w procesie jak najbardziej jest to prawidlowe, tylko warningi sa (LACHE - pamieci)
            if s = "00" then
                y <= a;
            else
                y <=(others => '0');  
            end if;

            if s = "01" then
                y <= b;
            else
                y <=(others => '0');  
            end if;

            if s = "10" then
                y <= c;
            else
                y <=(others => '0');  
            end if;

            if s = "11" then -- zadziala tylko ten if bo jest sekwencyjnie ywkonywane i albo da 'd' albo 0000
                y <= d;
            else
                y <=(others => '0');  
            end if;


            end process;

        end arch_mux7;



     -- configuration conf_mux of mux is
        --for arch_mux6
        --end for;
      --end conf_mux;
```

Comment: First off, it should be clear that this code is only meant as an educational exercise. Nobody writes (or should write) muxes at this detail, or in seven different implementations for the same mux. 
Perhaps you should tag your question as "homework"

Comment: It looks like your code reflects your block diagram. What exactly do you want to change? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i convert entity of bloch
>   which takes 4 inputs to 2 inputs?

Do you mean make your input `a` to `h` and output `x`,`y`,`z` 2 bits wide rather than 4?

Just change the relevant `generic`, surely!